# Path variable usage as annotation param

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I've got simple spring mvc controller

```
@GetMapping("/{s}")
@PreAuthorize("@myMethod(s, Constant.WRITE")
public ResponseEntity<MyDto> getDto(
    @PathVariable("s") String s
) {}
```

So the problem is to pass the path variable to PreAuthorize annotation.
Can SPeL help me in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Expression-Based Access Control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html)

```
@GetMapping("/{s}")
@PreAuthorize("@myMethod(#s, Constant.WRITE")
public ResponseEntity<MyDto> getDto(
    @PathVariable("s") String s
) {}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it's called Expression-Based Access Control. You can read about it here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/el-access.html. There is section called 26.2.2 Path Variables in Web Security Expressions